# Alternative for entryComponent in Angular 17

Tags: angular

In Angular 17,
entry components are no longer allowed and I am getting compilation error. when I commented entry components lines. The compile errors are gone but some of the components not working on the application run.
can anybody let me know the solution for it or any alternative for it?
Thanks

I tried to comment out entry components lines. but due to that some of the components not working like click.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 17, entry components are no longer allowed, and you may face compilation errors if you have used them in your code. If you have commented out the entry components lines and are still facing issues with some of the components not working, there are a few things you can try.

One alternative to entry components is to use the ngComponentOutlet directive. This directive allows you to dynamically load a component based on a variable or expression. Here's how you can use it:

In your template, add an element with the ngComponentOutlet directive and bind it to a component variable or expression.

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myComponent"></ng-container>
```

In your component class, define the myComponent variable or expression.

```
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';  
  
@Component({  
  selector: 'app-my-container',  
  template: `  
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="myComponent"></ng-container>  
  `  
})  
export class MyContainerComponent {  
  myComponent = MyComponent;  
}
```

This will dynamically load the MyComponent when the MyContainerComponent is rendered.

Another alternative is to use lazy loading. Lazy loading allows you to load components only when they are needed, reducing the initial load time of your application. Here's how you can use it:

1 - Create a separate module for the component that you want to lazy load.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { MyLazyLoadedComponent } from './my-lazy-loaded.component';




@NgModule({  
  declarations: [MyLazyLoadedComponent],  
  imports: [CommonModule],  
})  
export class MyLazyLoadedModule {}
```

2 - In your app routing module, define a route for the lazy-loaded module using the loadChildren property.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';  
  
const routes: Routes = [  
  {  
    path: 'lazy',  
    loadChildren: () =>  
      import('./my-lazy-loaded.module').then((m) => m.MyLazyLoadedModule),  
  },  
];  
  
@NgModule({  
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],  
  exports: [RouterModule],  
})  
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

3 - In your template, add a link to the lazy-loaded module.

```
<a routerLink="/lazy">Lazy Loaded Component</a>
```

This will load the MyLazyLoadedComponent only when the user navigates to the /lazy route.